# Superscript equality formula

Tags: formatting, equations

I want to write such equation:[image] .

However, I don't know how to write second equality here (a=12). Actually, it is not even an equality, it is some kind of a pointer that was placed above. How to do it?

P.S.
The closest thing to what I need is \cancelto{}{}
[image],

but I don't need the arrow, I need "=".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\equalscript[1]{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{40}{$\scriptscriptstyle=$}^{\!#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
x = 4\cdot a^{\equalscript{12}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one prefers not having to type out the superscript `^` invocation each time, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\equalscript[1]{^{\rotatebox[origin=bottom]{40}{$\scriptscriptstyle=$}^{\!#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x = 4\cdot a\equalscript{12}
\]
\end{document}
```